# Intellij Idea - open recent project keyboard shortcut key

Tags: intellij-idea

If I'm working in a project, is there a keyboard shortcut key to open a recent project (equivalent of File > Open Recent)? I'm on a Mac.

It seems like you can't even assign a shortcut to "Open Recent" in the Keymap either.

Comment: On windows and IJ 14, one can assign a hotkey for `Reopen project` which will popup a list of recent projects when used. If this is what you need, I can provide an answer with a couple of screenshots

Comment: I'm using Intellij 14.1 on Mac and there is no Reopen Project for which a keymap can be assigned. Is this in the File menu in Windows?

Comment: 14.1.4 here and yes, there's a **File** > **Reopen Project** menu item

Comment: On the Mac, there is a File > Open Recent menu item that, for some reason, is no mappable in Keymap :(

Comment: Have you tried right clicking it in the keymap window?

Comment: Yeah. The problem is that "Open Recent" is a folder not an item. It contains the recent projects as items.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87233/discussion-between-morfic-and-stepanian).

Comment: I just installed the latest version (14.1.4) and it seems like they have fixed the bug. I had version 14.1.1. Please add an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**NOTE**: The following is based on IJ 14.1.4 running on W7. There may be minor discrepancies on other OS', such as *Reopen Project* being named *Open recent* on Mac

1. Go to **Settings** > **Keymap** and scroll down to **Main menu**. Expand **File**, select **Reopen Project** and assign a shortcut, such as <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

[image: Keymap dialog]

2. When used, it will popup a list with your recent projects:

[image: Reopen project popup menu]

Comment: Also, there is a quick-search functionality in the popup which is a life saver in my case. (IJ 2017.2)

Answer (score 6):

Another approach that doesn't require adding any keyboard shortcuts:

Press `cmd + shift + a` *(Mac)* / `ctrl + shift + a` *(Windows)* to perform an action search, then search for "open recent".

Answer (score 0):

**On MacOS:**
Settings > Keymap > Main menu > File > Open Recent
Right click > Add Keyboard Shortcut
Press a combo, click OK to close shortcut dialog, click OK to save and close Settings.
Hit your combination and a dialog with a list of recently opened projects will appear.

**Pro tips:**

- When the dialog is open you can start typing to filter project list
- You can also delete projects you don't need in recents by clicking on "Manage Projects.." and removing them by pressing 'x' next to project name.